# Floating Paragraphs not contained within <div> Border

Tags: html, css

I have made two floating paragraphs side by side, underneath an h1 element, all contained within a div. When I apply a border to the whole div, the floated paragraphs are not included within it. The following sentences aren't being contained within the green border:

```
<div class="about">
  <h1 id="aboutLink">About</h1>
  <p id="col1of2">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
  <p id="col2of2">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
</div>

#col1of2, #col2of2 {
  width:  30%;
  margin-left: 14%;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
} 

.about {
   border: green solid 3px;
}
```

See a js-fiddle here:
    https://jsfiddle.net/6aaruxLd/3/

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because elements with `float` are outside the documents normal flow. You need to add a `clear:both` element after them to fix that:

```
    <div class="about">
        ...
        <br style="clear:both;" />
    </div>
```

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6aaruxLd/4/)